# What does P::************ mean in Boost assert.hpp file?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

In [boost/mpl/assert.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/mpl/assert.hpp), I saw something like this:

```
template<class Pred>
struct eval_assert {
    typedef typename extract_assert_pred<Pred>::type P;
    typedef typename P::type p_type;
    typedef typename ::boost::mpl::if_c<p_type::value,
        AUX778076_ASSERT_ARG(assert<false>),
        failed ************ P::************
    >::type type;
};
```

If the first `************` can be treated as pointers of struct failed, the `P::************` really doesn't make any sense to me. Is this standard C++?

Comment: Yes. It's a multiple-level pointer to pointer to member of `P`.

Comment: ( Such nested pointers exist? :/ )

Comment: Pointerception ...

Comment: @deviantfan In production code? You would be surprised. ;) But the point here is to cause a compilation failure by trying to refer to a member of `P` with a very high degree of certainty that it won't exist. (In C++11 you'd probably just use `static_assert(false)` instead, but of course Boost has to be portable to pre-C++11.)

Comment: Side note: The 12-level pointer probably has something to do with the minimum required by the C standard.

Comment: @PaulDraper it's actually reading [_`hunter2hunter2hunter2hunter2`_](http://www.bash.org/?244321) here

Comment: pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a member of type P

Comment: I think I've seen this used as a way to make hacking a game more difficult.

Answer (score 100):

The point of this code is to help the compiler produce "visible" error messages.

In pre `static_assert` era, compiling a template-heavy code could easily produce ~100 lines of error messages even for a single mistake, and 99% of those lines are often meaningless.

The 10 pointers trick is useful to point out the actual error, for example:

```
 BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((std::is_same<T,U>));
```

With `T=void*` and `U=char*` compiled with gcc produces ~10 error lines, but you can easily see the relevant one:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ std::is_same<void*, char*>::************)’
```

Answer (score 45):

It's a pointer-to-pointer-to-...-member of type `P`, where the member is a data member of type pointer-to-pointer-to-...-`failed`.

In this case the goal is simply to cause compilation to fail by referring to a member of `P` with a very high degree of probability that it won't exist.  In C++11 you'd just use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) instead, but of course Boost needs to be portable to pre-C++11 dialects.

Answer (score 19):

`F P::*` is a "pointer to member of `P` of type `F`".

`F P::**` is a "pointer to pointer to member of `P` of type `F`".

More `*`s adds more "pointer to" in front.

In this case, `F` is `failed ************`, i.e., "pointer to pointer to ... pointer to `failed`".